# How to write well predicate(not between)

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I write code follwing

```
testb :-
    X::1..10,
    V1 = 3,
    V2 = 6,
    testbb(X,V1,V2),
    writeln(X).

testbb(X,V1,V2) :-
    (
      count(I,V1,V2),param(X,V1,V2) do 
      X#\=I 
    ).


?- testb.
Yes (0.00s cpu)
_385{[1, 2, 7 .. 10]}
```

It works well, but i think it isn't efficient

Thanks very much :)

Comment: It's too fast to measure in this tiny example, so how can you tell it's not efficient? Besides, which Prolog dialect is this? ECLiPSe?

Comment: Yes, eclipse clp, I write this code by logical OOP, I don't understand well logical of prolog, so, i can't confirm :(

Answer (score 2):

You could confine the domain of `X` to lie outside the range within `V1` to `V2` by:

```
not_between(X, Lower, Upper) :-
     % it is not the case that X is both greater and 
     % equal to Lower, and less than or equal to Upper: 
    #\ ((X #>= Lower) #/\ (X #=< Upper)).
```

Replace your `testbb/3` with `not_between/3`. This definition ensures that `X` cannot take on `Lower` and `Upper` values exactly; you could use the range constraints `#<` and `#>` instead if you wish them to be included in the domain for `X`.

This is tested and working with SWI-Prolog. To use CLP(FD) in a SWI-Prolog file, make sure you import the CLP(FD) library at the top of your source file in a directive, like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Comment: which prolog do you use ? it doesn't work at eclipse clp and SWI-Prolog,  thanks :)

Comment: This is tested working with SWI-Prolog using CLP(FD). I used `X in 1..10, not_between(X,3,6)` to test the predicate, and the domain of X is indeed partitioned into the sets defined by `[1,2]` and `[7,..,10]`.